# Unix: How to find the name of the ethernet interface through which I'm logged in

Tags: linux, networking, unix-shell, multi-homed

We have multihomed servers. And to simplify things, I would like to know the dns of the interface trough which I'm logged in. (e.g. to set PS1 thus it can be used in scp commands)

My solution for that problems seems to be rather complicated.
=> is there a easier/simpler and more portable way?

```
ORIGIN_NAME=`who -m | cut -d\( -f2 | cut -d\) -f1`
ORIGIN_IP=`getent hosts $ORIGIN_NAME | awk '{ print $1; }'`
INTERFACE_NAME=`ip route get $ORIGIN_IP | grep dev | awk '{ print substr($0,index($0,"dev")+4,4); }'`
INTERFACE_IP=`ifconfig -a $INTERFACE_NAME | grep inet | awk ' { print $2; }' | cut -d: -f2`
getent hosts $INTERFACE_IP | awk '{ print $NF; }'
```

Comment: How do you use the name of the ethernet device in for example scp ?

Comment: If I have to copy something to a server and I'm already logged in! (network pathes are pretty different in different zones, thus I'm always unsure, which is the right interface to use...)

Comment: I'm using putty to log in (using predefined sessions), but pscp.exe to copy files. Maybe, that's the mistake :) But currently, it's useful to have the used interface in the PS1 prompt

Comment: Argh... "name of the interface" is misleading! That would be e.g. "eth0". What I'm obviously searching for is the dns of the IP mapped to the interface I have used to reach the server!

Comment: There is no guarantee that there will be a PTR (or similar host) record that will give the name related to the ip address.

Comment: If you're using the OpenSSH server (and maybe other flavors), you can look at the `SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable to get the IP address of the client side.

Comment: @ThomasSV Get the IP like MarkPlotnick says, then use `host x.x.x.x` to look it up. But as lain says, you may not get anything or not what you're expecting because it's a reverse address.

Comment: What do you mean with "reverse addr."? It should be the dns entry for that IP. And since it's a inhouse datacenter, I'm pretty sure every IP is named. Was that your concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Plotnick has the easiest one! Just use `echo $SSH_CONNECTION` it will output something like client-IP, client-Port, server-IP, server-port the first is your IP (from where you login) the second is the IP or host you are connected to. Credit should go to Mark on this one.

Comment: Thanks! Credit should go to Mark, but he just answered in a comment... Please correct your answer: the fields are: client-IP, client-Port, server-IP, server-port.  Thx to you both!

Answer (score 0):

```
ip route get ${SSH_CONNECTION%% *}
```

Comment: ip route get is unneccessary, since SSH_CONNECTION already contains the IP of the used Interface on the Server side